# trick about xargs and wildcard

Tags: bash, xargs

I have two directories which are 'dir1' and 'dir2', and I want to output all the contents of the two directories. So, I take use of  bash command 'xargs' to make it by only one command line. The command is "echo '1 2' | xargs -d ' ' -I @ -t  sh -c 'cat    dir@/*'", but the result is odd.

```
[u@10 /data1/walter]$ echo '1 2' | xargs -d ' ' -I @ -t  sh -c 'cat dir@/*' 
sh -c cat dir1/*   <<<<  This output is normal
1                  <<<<  This is all content in dir1
sh -c cat dir2     
/*                 <<<< these two lines are odd, it looks like xargs insert a '\n' between 'dir2' and '/*'
cat: dir2: Is a directory    <<<< as a result, 'cat' can't receive argument 'dir2'
sh: line 1: /bin: is a directory   <<<< and command line '/*' is error
```

Comment: Try using find dir*. Yon can visit the man page of find to control/format the output that way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` automatically appends a newline to its output, so `xargs` is getting two values to substitute for `@`: `1` and `2\n`. An immediate fix is to disable the newline using

```
echo -n '1 2' | xargs ...
```

or (more portably)

```
printf '1 2' | xargs ...
```

However, as others have pointed out, using `xargs` for this is probably more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something in your question but you can simply pass both directories to `ls`:

```
ls dir1/* dir2/*
```

This can be simplified using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
ls dir{1,2}/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify the two directories:

```
ls dir1 dir2
```

or perhaps

```
find dir1 dir2
```

if you want a more complex solution (i.e. finding across multiple directories)